# md5 hash function in binary format

Tags: macos, terminal, md5

I am trying to calculate the digests of a file using md5 algorithm. I am asked to format the output to be in binary not hex. So this is my command in terminal (I use mac):

openssl dgst -md5 -binary ~/Documents/msg_Joudi.txt > ~/Documents/hash.txt

this generates hash.txt file, but its content is not in binary format, and I do not know where is the error.

Comment: That looks right to me. I copied your code, ran `$ file -I ~/Desktop/hash.txt` from terminal to check the file type, and it returned:

`/Desktop/hash.txt: application/octet-stream; charset=binary`

What did you get instead of binary?

Comment: This is what in the file: 
y«I:yÌ˘m.§6ßı6B

Comment: @user233531 Your way of creating a binary md5 is correct. Output looks good, as well. Why do you think the file is not binary? And, besides, this is not a programming related question.

Comment: Binary should be 0s and 1s right? Sorry I frequently see questions in many topics

Comment: @NikolaiRuhe Why do you believe this is not a programming related question? He's trying to calculate an algorithm programmically and format the output. Which forum would you categorize this under?

Comment: @user233531 No, a "binary file" means that the contents are not encoded is some common text encoding but just contain random bytes. Sending a binary file to the terminal will interpret it's contents in the Terminal's encoding, for example UTF-8. This kind of output is usually not meaningful.

Comment: I read sth on the web just now. I think binary files cannot be read without hex editors, is that right?

Comment: @femmestem The OP uses the command line to create an md5 from the contents of a file. This kind of question is better suited to (superuser)[http://superuser.com].

Comment: @user233531 You can print the contents of your md5 file like so: `hexdump ~/Documents/hash.txt`. This will print the contents in hex. Compare that to just running `openssl dgst -md5 ~/Documents/msg_Joudi.txt`

Answer (score 6):

Create MD5 hash of file: msgFile.txt `>` Convert to **Binary** and save:

```bash
cat msgFile.txt | openssl dgst -md5 -binary > hash.bin.txt
```

Save binary in **Base64** format:

```bash
cat msgFile.txt | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | base64 > hash.bin.b64.txt
```

Save binary in **Hexadecimal** representation:

```bash
cat msgFile.txt | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | xxd -ps -c16 > hash.bin.hex.txt
```

Use Python to convert binary to **Integers**:

```bash
python -c "print(int('$(cat msgFile.txt | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | xxd -ps -c16)', 16))" > hash.bin.int.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP says he wants binary and then says "Binary should be 0s and 1s right?".
Although, probably unlikely, if he really wants a binary number output, do this:

```
$ echo -e "xx\nyy" >in.txt
$ perl -ln0777e 'use Digest::MD5 "md5"; print "0b".unpack("B*",md5($_))' <in.txt
0b001111000101011000010000100101100011010101000101111000101000000011110110011010110011010000!
```

Meaning of above:

- slurp in whole file into $_, calculate md5 digest on $_ to create binary data
- use unpack to convert binary data to binary number string

If he really wants binary data, modify the above:

```
$ perl -ln0777e 'use Digest::MD5 "md5"; print md5 $_' <in.txt >binout.txt
```